# Can a model be both smooth and flat shaded?

Tags: mesh, objects

I wonder is it possible to have 50% smooth shading and 50% flat shading in blender cycles, applied to an created mesh?

[image]
[image]

The 1st image has a smooth shading on it and the 2nd has flat shading , is it possible to have 50% smooth shading and 50% flat shading? or 30% smooth and 70% flat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can choose which parts of your model are flat or smooth shaded from the <kbd>W</kbd> specials menu. Make a selection of faces and choose *Shade Smooth* or *Shade Flat* depending on what you want to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify you can set smooth or flat shading per face, but there is no middle ground, it is either one or the other.

Comment: ok ty , that solved my problem:)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is posible to create this as an effect. Apply a smooth shade to the material then add 2 sub surf modifiers like the image below.[image: note how the sub surf modifiers are set]